# How implement django.views.generic for logoutPage/loginPage if earlier used request?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

What is the best practice for migration from **request** to django.views.generic?
How implement django.views.generic for logoutPage/loginPage if earlier used request?

```
#This my model.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

```
#This my view.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic import ListView



def logoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')

def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
       if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print("working")
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/')
       context={}
       return render(request,'book/templates/login.html',context)
```

Comment: Do you want it from LoginView?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in implementing through from LoginView.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the simplest way or a slightly more complicated but giving more possibilities in the future.

If you don't need any modifications (and usually one doesn't at early stage), you can do it directly in your main **urls.py** file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='book/templates/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

Alternatively you can create your own classes, that inherit from that views. Obviously, you can set proper `path()` for each in **urls.py**.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

class LoginPage(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name='book/templates/login.html'
    ...

class LoginPage(auth_views.LogoutView):
    ...
```

For both you can set redirect page with variables set in **settings.py** with wanted path name (it means the `name="welcome"` part):

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "user_profile"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "come_back_please"
```